# Is posting the message on Kinesis stream asynchronous?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-kinesis

Is posting the message on Kinesis stream asynchronous, or there any way to run it asynchronously using GoLang SDK API?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/kinesis/) appears to be pretty thorough about which operations are asynchronous, so I would say no: posting a message is not asynchronous. But that only makes sense anyway--how can it return an error, if the operation hasn't yet completed?

But can you make it asynchronous? Of course. In Go it's trivial to make anything asynchronous--just run it in a goroutine.

If you're new to goroutines, [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1) is a great introduction to the concept.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's synchronous.

When you call PutRecord API endpoint, a record is written in Kinesis, and as a response "ShardId" and "SequenceNumber" is returned. That displays where the recorded data is placed upon a stream (shard).

See document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html